# The specified task executable location "...\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\..\tools\csc.exe" is invalid

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I downloaded my code from TFS to a new folder on my C: but it seems Im having trouble with the compiler it seems.

I deleted the .suo file but I still have the same problem and 68 warnings.

Because I never encountered such a problem I dont know which information is relevant to post here in order to solve it, this is what I see in the error list:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The specified task executable location "C:\Projects\GigHub\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build..\tools\csc.exe" is invalid.   GigHub**

Now the thing is, csc.exe does not exist on that folder. Also, Im seeing a lot of warnings in regards of different files.

Answer (score 11):

## Reason

Your project is set to use a **.NET Compiler package** for building and compiling assemblies.

By default, the compiler lives in the .NET framework folder:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

But if your project includes a **.NET Compiler package** then an alternative compiler will be used from within your project:

```
YOUR_PROJECT_DIR\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\csc.exe
```

It could be that the internal compiler package was not added to your repository correctly. Try the following steps and make sure everything is added to your source control.

## Solution

You need to either Uninstall or Re-install the **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** package:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution
3. Go to **Installed** tab and find **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** package
4. Uninstall the package from your project
5. Try to build your project now. For me it worked and unless you really need that package, *you can leave it out*. Be careful as the new versions support for example C# 6+ and you might need it to use the latest language features.
6. If you need the package then go ahead and find it in the **Browse** tab and install the latest stable version.
7. Build the project and if everything works, make sure you commit changes to your code repository.