# The specified task executable location ......csc.exe is invalid error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, csc

I have a project on TFS that is working on everyone else's machine, except mine. When building I get the error that can be seen in the image. "The specified task executable location csc.exe is invalid." currently trying to repair VS 2017 now.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The specified task executable location "...\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\..\tools\csc.exe" is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686183/the-specified-task-executable-location-packages-microsoft-net-compilers-1-3)

Answer (score 20):

Based on the message, seems the `csc.exe` is damaged.

Just try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Navigate to the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` package location, delete
  the package folder, then rebuild. Generally the package will be
  restored automatically during the build.

  `YOUR_PROJECT_DIR\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1`
- Uninstall and Re-install the **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** package:

  1. Open Visual Studio
  2. Go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution
  3. Go to **Installed** tab and find **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** package
  4. Uninstall the package from your project
  5. Try to build your project now. (Thus it will use the default compiler which lives in the .NET framework folder:
     `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe`)
  6. If you really need the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` package then go ahead and find it in the **Browse** tab and install the latest stable
     version.
  7. Build the project and if everything works, make sure you commit changes to your code repository.
- You can also try to run below command to uninstall and reinstall the
  Nuget packages from the Package Manager Console: See [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/)

  `Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.6.1`

  `Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.6.1`

Comment: also you might need to edit your project .csproj file and remark out the the file's it's looking for for nuget. Nuget doesn't remove that from your project file.

Comment: Not Working Any Update?

Answer (score 5):

Remove Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform and Microsoft.Net.Compilers Nuget Packages.

Comment: This indeed worked for me, so good answer.  None-the-less, I have to ask "Why Microsoft, why?"  On the surface, this seems a very harmful thing to do, so the fact that it makes things better is just really odd.

Answer (score 2):

Installing MSBuild 2015 will resolve the issue.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159

Comment: The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csc.exe" is invalid.  Now it is not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this question even though my error was "The specified task executable csc.exe **could not be run**" when pulling down existing web project with unit tests and trying to run it locally for the first time.

I was able to resolve this by building each project individually in my solution.